# How to add extensions to VS Codium (open source version) from github repos

Tags: vscodium

Lot of VSCode extensions are missing in VSCodium. Looking for a simple way to add the missing extensions from their github repos. Does something like this exist?

I've looked for similar answers but nothing explains a simple way to do this

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found the answer after posting the question

Find the vsix file at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/, download it (under the version history tab)

```
cd ~/Downloads
codium --install-extension clara-copilot-0.0.1.vsix
```